# Serverless - DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

Need help with this error -

> {
>     "errorMessage": "RequestId: 18120028-124f-11e9-9e46-b3db6ae39b34 Process exited before completing request"
>   }

Also, I have the following in the logs

> 2019-01-07T07:37:32.797Z  18120028-124f-11e9-9e46-b3db6ae39b34    UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'BillingMode' found in params
>       at ParamValidator.fail (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:50:37)
>       at ParamValidator.validateStructure (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:77:14)
>       at ParamValidator.validateMember (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:88:21)
>       at ParamValidator.validate (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:34:10)
>       at Request.VALIDATE_PARAMETERS (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:125:42)
>       at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
>       at callNextListener (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:95:12)
>       at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:85:9
>       at finish (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:320:7)
>       at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:338:9

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "xxxxxxx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.382.0",
    "serverless-dynamodb-local": "^0.2.35",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "dynamoose": "^1.3.0",
    "factory-girl": "^5.0.4",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.23.0",
    "serverless-aws-documentation": "^1.1.0",
    "serverless-mocha-plugin": "^1.9.1",
    "serverless-offline": "^3.31.3",
    "serverless-plugin-include-dependencies": "^3.2.1",
    "serverless-reqvalidator-plugin": "^1.0.3",
    "serverless-webpack": "^5.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.27.1"
  }
}
```

Here is the action -

```
'use strict';

const Insider = require('../models/insider').Insider;
const InsiderTest = require('../models/insider').InsiderTest;

module.exports.index = (_event, _context, callback) => {

  const klass = (process.env.STAGE == 'test') ? InsiderTest : Insider

  klass.scan().exec((_err, data) => {
    if (data.count == 0) {
      callback(null, {
        statusCode: 422,
        error: 'No Insiders'
      });
      return;
    }
    const response = {
      data: {
        results: data
      },
      statusCode: 200
    }
    callback(null, response);
  });
};
```

serverless.yml

```
service: vs-aws-lambda-serverless-services

package:
  exclude:
    - node_modules/**
  include:
    - models/**

plugins:
  - serverless-reqvalidator-plugin
  - serverless-aws-documentation
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-dynamodb-local
  - serverless-mocha-plugin
  - serverless-plugin-include-dependencies

#############################################
# Standard Serverless Definition
#############################################
provider:
  name: aws
  region: xxxxxxx
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  stage: xxxx
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamoDB:DescribeTable
        - dynamoDB:Query
        - dynamoDB:Scan
        - dynamoDB:GetItem
        - dynamoDB:PutItem
        - dynamoDB:UpdateItem
        - dynamoDB:DeleteItem
      Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:xxxxxxx:*:*"
#############################################

# #############################################
# # Model Definitions - API Gateway
# #############################################
custom:
  documentation:
    models:
      -
        name: CreateSuccessResponse
        contentType: 'application/json'
        schema:
          type: object
          properties:
            message:
              type: string
            statusCode:
              type: string
      -
        name: xxxxxxsRequest
        contentType: 'application/json'
        schema:
          type: object
          required:
            - name
          properties:
            name:
              type: string
            profileImage:
              type: string
            gender:
              type: string
            fullDescription:
              type: string
            shortDescription:
              type: string
            interests:
              type: array
            personalities:
              type: array
            travelledCities:
              type: array
            tribes:
              type: array
            funFacts:
              type: array

  dynamodb:
    start:
      migrate: true
#############################################

#############################################
# Lambda Functions
#############################################
functions:
  listInsiders:
    handler: insiders/index.index
    events:
      - http:
          path: insiders
          method: get
          cors: true
          integration: lambda
          response:
            headers:
              Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
          documentation:
            methodResponses:
              -
                statusCode: '200'
                responseModels:
                  "application/json": CreateSuccessResponse            
#############################################

#############################################
# Resource Definitions
#############################################
resources:
  Resources:
    xxxxxxsDynamoDBTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          -
            AttributeName: uuid
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          -
            AttributeName: uuid
            KeyType: HASH
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        TableName: 'table_name'
    requestBody:
      Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::RequestValidator'
      Properties:
        Name: 'requestBody'
        RestApiId:
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
        ValidateRequestBody: true
#############################################
```

Comment: Could you show us your serverless.yml ?

Comment: @QuentinHayot I have updated it with `serverless.yml`

Comment: Fixed the issue. The problem was with the definition of API Gateway section. Removed it and everything works fine. Will debug to see what's wrong in there.